# how to find datakeys value while downloading from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am getting following error while clicking on download button in gridvioew 
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
my aspx code is

```
<asp:GridView ID ="gvDetails" runat ="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
<Columns >
<asp:BoundField DataField ="auto_id" ReadOnly ="True" HeaderText="Sr No." />
<asp:BoundField DataField ="topic_name" ReadOnly ="True" HeaderText ="Announcement" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="File Path">
<ItemTemplate >
<asp:LinkButton ID ="lnkDownload" runat ="server" Text="Download" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

my code for downloading is 
protected void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
int field = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value .ToString ());
SqlDataReader dr = MclsAssignment.getDownload(field);
if (dr.Read())
{
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + dr["mfile_name"] + "\"");
Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["file_data"]);
Response.End();
}
}
catch (Exception)
{       
throw;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the exception when no row is selected. Therefore, you need to check that

```
gvrow.RowIndex
```

is greater than -1.

```
protected void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    if(gvrow.RowIndex < 0)   //return if user hasn't selected any row
        return;
    LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
    GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    int field = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value .ToString ());
    SqlDataReader dr = MclsAssignment.getDownload(field);
    if (dr.Read())
    {
      Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + dr["mfile_name"] + "\"");
      Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["file_data"]);
      Response.End();
     }
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {       
     throw;
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of gvrow.RowIndex?

Comment: gvrow.RowIndex value is 1 after selecting gridview

Comment: do you have any datakey at index of your gridview?

Comment: you haven't specified any datakeynames in your grid

Comment: after adding datakeyname in the gridview error is solved but "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed." the new error is came....i am using three tier architecture here..and i haven't close connection anywhere

Comment: can  you post the line ?

Comment: if (dr.Read()) after reaching this line i got error "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed"

Comment: my DAL Function is         private SqlDataReader getDownload(string sql)
        {
            SqlDataReader dr;
            using (SqlConnection con = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection())
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getInfo", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@query", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sql;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
            return dr;
        }

Comment: it would be best if you post it as a seperate question

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check gvRow.RowIndex for -1. If the user did not select a row in the gridview, it will give you the exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID ="lnkDownload" runat ="server" Text="Download" RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' OnClick="lnkDownload_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>


---------------------------------------------------------------
int field = Convert.ToInt32(lnkbtn.Attributes["RowIndex"]);
```

Hope this will get you rowIndex However if yous till facing problems please elaborate your question and tell exactly where are you getting error??

However using Command event will be more efficeient .

Comment: i am getting error on the following line code : int field = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value .ToString ())

Answer (score 0):

Please try Row Command event it is the simplest solution for your question

*Example*

```
<asp:GridView ID ="gvDetails" runat ="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
<Columns >
  <asp:BoundField DataField ="auto_id" ReadOnly ="True" HeaderText="Sr No." />
  <asp:BoundField DataField ="topic_name" ReadOnly ="True" HeaderText ="Announcement" />
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="File Path">
    <ItemTemplate >
      <asp:LinkButton ID ="lnkDownload" runat ="server" Text="Download"   CommandName="Download"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("YourID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>    
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>




protected void gvDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.ToLower() == "application")
    {

          // write your code
    }
}
```